# Do I need to create separate applications for windows phone 8 and windows 8 desktop?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I want to create an app that is compatible with Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8, both desktop and tablet versions. My question is whether an application developed for Windows Phone 8 runs on Windows 8 tablet and desktop versions. I know I need to create separate views for the three; is that enough or do I need any additional steps? I want to use  SQLite database in Windows Phone 8. Is that compatible with the other versions too?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201744.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You will not be able to create a single assembly which can run on Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8.

You may be able to create libraries which you can reference in both projects or share code in other ways.

You will need to create separate UI for each platform. (Even if they end up looking the same-although that would probably not be a good idea.) Each platform has different conventions and ways users will expect apps to behave. You should respect these to avoid confusing users.

You can use SQLite on both Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8.